# Android kills the foreground service started by FCM message

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-workmanager, foreground-service

My app starts a long task (say uploading a file) when receives a data notification from FCM. This is how I managed to do that by starting a **foreground service**. It starts working well but stops after about 20 seconds.

As I read in the [FCM doumenttation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) *I have to handle any message within 20 seconds of receipt (10 seconds on Android Marshmallow)*. Ok! I thought that starting a foreground service is a kind of response to the message but it seems not!

Is there a mistake in my codes that stops after few seconds? Can I overcome this problem by switching from **foregroundService** to **Workmanager**, **AlarmManager** etc. and do they counted as a valid response to the FCM message?

This is my code in FireBaseMessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {

        final String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        final String tag = remoteMessage.getData().get("tag");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Uploader.class);
        i.putExtra("title", title);
        i.putExtra("body", body);

        if (tag.equals("start")) {
            i.putExtra("act", "start");
        }

        if (tag.equals("stop")) {
            i.putExtra("act", "stop");
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            this.startForegroundService(i);
        } else {
            this.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the uploader class which **starts foreground by showing a sticky notification** suing  `startForeground(1,mBuilder.build())`;

```
public class Uploader extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String tag = intent.getStringExtra("act");
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String body = intent.getStringExtra("body");
    showNotification(this,title,body,tag);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void showNotification(Context context, String title, String body, String tag) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = 1;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body);

    if (tag.equals("start")) {
        startForeground(1,mBuilder.build());
        startUploading();
    }
    if (tag.equals("stop")) {
        stopUploading();
    }
}
```

.

Comment: try using IntentService instead of Service. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: also please check the logcat if you can find any logs related to the closing of your service.

Comment: Apart from this, different devices have different behaviours. Like all the apps are by default put into battery optimization category. Try to remove it from the settings.